# Ant Build file with junit test for java project

Tags: ant

I am trying to write an android build file that compiles, creates a jar executes it and also runs a bunch of test files. This is what I have so far, but not sure how to proceed with writing the test block. I have looked around but an example of a build file with junit testing but haven't found any..an example of a ant file with junit would be helpful please

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="test.dir"    value="${build.dir}/test"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="com.arkangelx.classes.ATMLauncher"/>
<property name="TALK" value="true" />



<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>

    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"   verbose="${TALK}"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>


<target name="test" depends="run">
    <mkdir dir="${test.dir}"/>
    <test destfile="${test.dir}/${ant.project.name}.test" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <junit>
              <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
              <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
              <test name="TestExample" />
            </junit>
        </test>
    </target>


<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `test` element must be a sub-element of the `junit` task. There are several exemples available in (surprinsingly) the [documentation of the junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).